# phpMyAdmin Password

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL database through yahoo hosting and am unable to login with my username and password.  don't know if it's been changed or what. I wanted to know if there was a way to maybe configure the phpMyAdmin config files for a fixed user, so I can go in and set a new password. Let me know if this is possible or any other way that doesn't involve a shell because yahoo doesn't offer that. I need a way to get into my database.

Thanks

Comment: Kind of a question better suited for server fault.  This has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have shell or ftp access to the mysql servers my.cnf file (I doupt it) there is no way to recover/fix your password. You can possibly contact yahoo support, but I doubt there is much they could do either.

Or try this.

http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/webhosting/mysql/mysql-16.html